# Adding a condition to multiplication totals

Tags: sql

Is there a if, then, else or something similar that will take the number of credits and multiply the cost to get a total (as it does now) but add a condition that will only multiply up to 12 and credits 12 or below multiplies as normal.

For example: student is taking 15 credits * credit cost = cost of 12 credits.
student is taking 6 credits * credit cost = 6 credits.

Current code:
termCreds_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT StudentSched.xxx, Students.LastName, Students.FirstName, ISNULL(Students.CredCost, 0) AS credCost, SUM(Classes.Credits) AS Credz, ROUND((SUM(Classes.Credits))*Students.CredCost,2) AS TermCost,

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Use CASE expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want the `case` statement.  Something like this:

```
select (case when sum(credits) >= 15 then 100 * sum(credits)
             when sum(credits) >= 12 then 120 * sum(credits)
             else 150 * sum(credits)
        end)
```